# Inserting assets in the place of the 3d cursor using a script

Tags: scripting, asset-browser

I'm trying to create a script using ChatGPT that will put resources selected in the asset browser window into the 3d window in place of the 3d cursor without having to manually drag them to the right place.
I would like to use this method because some of my assets have to be rotated 90 degrees by their nature, and manually dragging them makes it necessary to rotate them 90 degrees each time.
At the moment the code looks like below, blender returns no errors but no assets are added to the 3d scene. Can you take a professional look?
Thx.

```
import bpy

def insert_assets_at_cursor():
    # Check that Asset Browser is open
    if not bpy.context.workspace.asset_browser.show_preview:
        print("Asset Browser is not open.")
        return
    
    # Take selected assets from Asset Browser
    selected_assets = bpy.context.workspace.asset_browser.collection_items
    
    # Get the current location of the 3D cursor
    cursor_location = bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
    
    # Insert the selected assets at the 3D cursor location
    for asset in selected_assets:
        bpy.ops.wm.append(
            directory=asset.directory,
            filename=asset.name,
            link=False,
            autoselect=True,
            active_collection=True
        )
        
        # Position the new object to the location of the 3D cursor
        new_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
        new_object.location = cursor_location
    
    print("Resources inserted at 3D cursor location.")

# Call the resource insert function when the script is run
insert_assets_at_cursor()
```